# Firefox GOJS Canvas is occasionally blank/empty on load

Tags: firefox, drag-and-drop, gojs

My company is utilizing GOJS to implement a drag-and-drop UI.

Occasionally in Firefox when the page is loaded, the div where the canvas should be is blank (white, no grid or draggable elements). The div will remain blank until either you resize the grid or attempt to navigate by dragging. At this point, the canvas works as expected. There are no errors or warnings in the console when this occurs.

Has anybody else run into this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are creating the Diagram a bit too early.  The page is being laid out asynchronously, and sometimes the DIV that holds the Diagram is resized after you have initialized the Diagram.

I suggest that you call **Diagram.requestUpdate()** once your page layout is completed.  Unfortunately GoJS cannot be informed when its DIV element has been resized -- there is no such DOM event that is reliable.  We can only listen for changes in the window size.

There is more discussion about this issue at http://gojs.net/latest/intro/resizing.html.